# Installing DirextX 9 SDK in Windows 7

Tags: installation, directx, managed

I'm following the following tutorials here:

http://www.euclideanspace.com/software/games/setup/dx9vb/installation/index.htm

On this page, I was *supposed* to download the DirextX 9.0 SDK.  It has to be 9.0 because it supports managed languages (like VB.net, C#.net, etc.).  After much searching, I *think* I came across a download link that worked for it (because Microsoft likes taking its links down every 2 minutes).  When I finally got it to start installing, I got an error saying that every operating system except Windows Vista and Windows 7 was supported.  What were the chances?  I swear this thing is trolling me.

Do you guys know of any ways that I can download this thing and get it so I can start working with it in C#/Vb.net?

**edit:**

Apparently, it also wanted me to be 32-bit (I'm running 64-bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article you are reading is 7 years old and Managed DirectX has long since become obsolete and unsupported. I suspect that you will continue to get all sorts of problems, so in my opinion your best option might be to set up a Windows XP virtual machine using something like VirtualBox. That way you can safely install old versions of the SDK that will work with Managed DirectX.

Rather than learning a deprecated framework you might be better off learning XNA which is Microsoft's newer game building framework, or alternatively [SlimDX](https://web.archive.org/web/20190806160509/http://slimdx.org/) which is a third-party replacement for Managed DirectX that is being kept up to date.

Edit: [This blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/) explains the situation and interestingly it seems that the Managed DirectX libraries were still being included at the time of the June 2010 release but were to be removed from future releases. Note that the release did not include documentation and samples though. You could potentially install the June 2010 release from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180821063334/http://www.softpedia.com:80/get/Programming/SDK-DDK/DirectX-Software-Development-Kit.shtml) but bear in mind it could potentially screw things up if you have later a later DX9 version installed.